# Github UI for OSX won't automatically track new files

Tags: macos, git, version-control, github

When adding new files to the git repository, and running git status, they show as untracked. That somewhat makes sense, but all the rest of our machines, when using the Windows or Mac GUI for github automatically track new files without having to go into terminal/command prompt and typing git add "thefilename.ext". We add new files every day and the GUI seems to take care of it.

However, on a new fresh install on a mac OSX, it WILL NOT track the new files automatically no matter what we try.

We have tried:

git add .
 git add "*"
 etc.

Is there a git command that allows the root folder to be tracked and any time ANY files are created from scratch it tracks them automatically? This is how other other machines seem to work, and for the life of me I cant figure out how we did it...

Answer (score 0):

You can start tracking all files with `git add --all`. You can commit all files known to git with `git commit -a`.

As far as I know, you can't make git automatically track files as they're added–though I'm not sure why you would want to.

Comment: I think that there are several users who would want this, at least for some projects